# Play iHeartRadio url on Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to play the following URL:http://wtkt-am.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/518/129345/v1/auth.akacast.akamaistream.net/wtkt-am using a standard MediaPlayer but it's not working. I opened the link in VLC and looked at the details and noticed that the extension of the file is mp4a, which I believe is an Apple format.

This URL is from iHeartRadio, and I think it's only for iPhone. I say this because I found the link here: http://www.iheartradio.com/cc-common/iphone/station_list.xml

However, I found the following link as well which would make one assume the same stations, but for Android: http://www.iheartradio.com/cc-common/android/station_list.xml

I'm trying to play station ID 1272, which is in the iPhone list, but not the Android list.

Anyone have any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: MP4a just means MP4 audio, and is not an Apple format. Android, by default, can play MP4 audio. Do you get an error message when you try to play it? Might as well post your code just to see if the problem is with it and not the stream.

Comment: If you're not sure if the stream you're using is Android-compatible, then first see if you can get any of the streams on the Android list to work.

Comment: My code works with other stream URLs so I know the code is fine. I also couldn't get any of the URLs in the Android list to work. I don't know what to do :/

Comment: What kind of streams where you trying before (and that you successfully got to work)? Some are XML-like files and some are media files that keep getting data added to them. This one seems to be the latter. Were the streams you were using before of the former type?